# Can we construct a probability space encompassing two stochastic processes on different probability spaces?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given two stochastic processes, $X$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega^X,(\mathcal{F}^X_t)_t), \mathcal{F}^X, P^X)$ and $Y$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega^Y,(\mathcal{F}^Y_t)_t), \mathcal{F}^Y, P^Y)$, is it possible to construct a filtered probability space $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F}_t)_t,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that both $X$ and $Y$ are stochastic processes on this space, individually?

Comment: One may possibly consider $(\Omega^X\times \Omega^Y,\mathscr{F}^X\otimes \mathscr{F}^Y,(\mathscr{F}^X_t\otimes \mathscr{F}^Y_t)_{t\geq 0},P^X\times P^Y)$ and the processes $X_t(\omega^X,\omega^Y):=X_t(\omega^X)$, $Y_t(\omega^X,\omega^Y):=Y_t(\omega^Y)$.